# NullPointerException when trying to load a button

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to open a  new activity.  When I do I get a null pointer exception.  Everything works untill the following code gets executed.

```
    Button RmTests =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRmTests);
    RmTests.setOnClickListener(AnsRmTest);
```

Here is a better look at the code.

```
public class DisplayTests extends ListActivity {
    private DbManagement mdbManager;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //mdbManager = new DbManagement(this);
        //mdbManager.open();
        Button RmTests =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRmTests);
        RmTests.setOnClickListener(AnsRmTest);

        //fillData();
    }
    private OnClickListener AnsRmTest = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{                
              System.out.println("fart");
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
              System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }       
    };
```

I am not sure why the activity would bomb out when it reaches the creation of a button.

Here is the XML as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="194dp" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNewExam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/strNewExam" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRmExams"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnRmTests"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnRmTests"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/strRmExams" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRmTests"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnNewExam"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNewExam"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRmExams"
        android:text="@string/strRmTest" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So with that being said I am the following code

```
setContentView(R.layout.moretime);
```

When I did that I get the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

I do have a list view as you can see about but it is called listView1 and I am not sure why I am getting this error message.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have revised my intial quesiton.  I have added the setContentView as suggested and now I am getting the following error.  java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'.  Inside the layout I do have a listview but it is called listView1.  I am not sure why I am getting the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the content of your layout to the activity first then initialize views.

```
   privae Button RmTests;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); // missing
    RmTests =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRmTests);
    RmTests.setOnClickListener(AnsRmTest);
    ... // rest of the code 
   }
```

You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Since you have not set the content to the activity, when you initialize your button you get `NullPointerException`.

ALso

`ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). **To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)**

In your xml replace

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
```

By

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also do you require a `FrameLayout`? Why not have just the listview and the buttons in the relative layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Edit:

From the comment below

You can do as below

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
String s[] = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, s);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

**`ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate()**.

If you need to have other views then you can define them in xml extend `ListActivity` in which case you need to have listview with id **"@android:id/list"**. Like i can have a list and a button at the button. So i need to have a listview with id as  **"@android:id/list"**.

Comment: Is it possible to have two ListViews on a given activity?

Comment: @user579426 yes you can have two listview in a activity. why do you think you can't?

Comment: but why do you require two listviews in a single activity?.

Comment: because you said the Listview must have an id = list.  How would you reference the second listView?  Pretty sure this is bad android design but you can have one listview display a set of records.  Then when you click on the first listView you could use that data to populate the second listView with more detailed data about what was clicked in the first listView.

Comment: @user579426 you can extend activity instead of listactivity have two listviews in xml and initialize on create and set the adapter to the same.

Comment: @user579426 you can have a listview then on click of listview row navigate to another activity. you can pass info to another actiivty using intent. you display the details in the next activity. you need not have  second listview for that purpose. every row click you can do the same.

Comment: Also if you have a tablet you can use fragments. one fragment to display a list and the other to display detailed data on click of listview row.

Comment: I'm cool with that but the problem I am having understanding is how can two listViews have the same id (id/list)?

Comment: @user579426 you can't have id same. What i mean is in the same xml file you cannot have two views with the same id. As suggested in the post You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Comment: That make sense that you can't have two listViews with the same id.  This is why I don't understand why my listViews id must be changed from ListView1 to list.  Why can't I have whatever id that I want for the ListView and when I call setContentView I don't know why it is looking id/list when it should be looking for id/listView1

Comment: @user579426 bcoz your extending `Listactivity`. You extend `Activity` then define id of your choice in xml. then setcontentview to your activity. then initialize your lsitview using the id of your choice.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand if I am extending then Listactivity then the id must equal list.  If I extended Activity I can make the id whatever I want it to be?

Comment: @user579426 exactly. One more point if you extend `ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen.  So you need not have `setContentView` if you have only list. But if you extend listactivity and also have other views then your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list".

Comment: @user579426 check the edit. Hope this clears your doubt on listview. if you still have doubts as a new question as this is leading to a discussion. To the original question asked i have already answered. So new doubt as a new question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in you Activity inside `onCreate` methode you forget to give `setContentView`

Before initializing the UI components you must set view for activity inside `onCreate` methode

ie `setContentView(R.layout.yourxml)`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);
    //mdbManager = new DbManagement(this);
    //mdbManager.open();
    Button RmTests =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRmTests);
    RmTests.setOnClickListener(AnsRmTest);
    //fillData();
}
```

**Additional Info**

also since your are using `ListActivty` you must provide listview id as

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="194dp" />
```

Otherwise it will cause another error

Answer (score 0):

Where do you tell your activity which xml it is supposed to load?

Try:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //mdbManager = new DbManagement(this);
    //mdbManager.open();
    Button RmTests =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRmTests);
    RmTests.setOnClickListener(AnsRmTest);

    //fillData();
}
```

replace "R.layout.main" with your xml file title. E.g. if it's Main_Layout.xml, replace it with  "R.layout.Main_Layout"

Answer (score 0):

Write

setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

after

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0):

**try be adding** `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the setContentView  .Here is the Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
Button RmTests =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRmTests);
    RmTests.setOnClickListener(AnsRmTest);

        }
```